# How to change editable attribute of selectonemenu depending on the result chosen from the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I have a selectonemenu of primefaces which has attribute editable assigned to true. Now, If I select one value from dropdown the editable attribute should be changed to false.

```html
<p:selectOneMenu id="oneMenu1" editable="true" style="width:100px" value="#{dashboardAction.selectRefreshRate}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{dashboardAction.vehicleAvail}" itemValue="#{dashboardAction.vehicleAvail}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{dashboardAction.getRRList()}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Can someone please suggest what needs to be done to change the attribute to false when a particular result from dropdown is selected.

I used the following JavaScript to do the same but failed.

```js
function disbalingFunction() {
    if (($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").text() == 'Never') || ($("#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected").text() == 'Default')) {
        $('#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1').attr("editable", "false");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ajax to call a function witch change your value like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="oneMenu1" editable="#{dashboardAction.myBooleanValue}" style="width:100px" value="#{dashboardAction.selectRefreshRate}">
        <p:ajax event="change" update="oneMenu1" 
                listener="#{dashboardAction.functionChangeToFalse()}" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{dashboardAction.vehicleAvail}" itemValue="#{dashboardAction.vehicleAvail}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{dashboardAction.getRRList()}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to insert an ajax event into selectonemenu tag?

```
<p:ajax event="valueChange" update="@form" oncomplete="disbalingFunction()"
            listener="#{SOMETHING_METHOD_TO_CALL}" />
```